# Presence Detection of Factory Machines for Their Traffic Management

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, rfid, detection

I'm currently planning a system for traffic management inside a factory (of its wheel kind machines).
Typically, I would use an inductive sensor which would react and indicate the vehicle presence. However, since I can't open up the ground to use these inductive sensores, I was thiking about using technologies such as RFID or NFC. In general, my idea would be sending a 5V signal whenever the presence is detected (using arduino, raspberry pi, microcontroller,etc). 
However, since I never used this kind of technology, I'm kind of reluctant due to false presences born from tags that are far from the receiver but still being detected. Has anybody done something like this? Thanks

Comment: What kind of machines?  What kind of factory for that matter.  You haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: ANd where would you place the RFID receiver, if you can't dig into ground?

Comment: Thinking aloud: paint large QR codes on the factory floor and have a camera on the front of each truck.  Every time a truck scans a code it pokes a server over WIFI and reports its status and the contents of the QR code.

Comment: You're going to use Raspberries and Arduinos in a factory? Do you expect to pass a certification of some sort afterwards?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I can fix them in the wall or the ceiling of the factory

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Probabily I will go into a microcontroller solution.

Comment: @Wossname that is an interesting idea. But do you think that the QR code detection would be accurate in terms of velocity? Since it would be made by a moving vehicle I'm kind of concerned with that.

Comment: @kohhworlwide, yes I reckon it would be OK if the QR codes were low-resolution (think large pixels) and printed quite large on the floor.  QR codes are designed to be readable even with substantial (30% or so) damage, so scuff marks from tyres and shoeprints would not be an issue for a long time and would be easy to replace: scrape off the old one and just stencil a new one down.

Comment: @Wossname What about the types of cameras? Are there any sort of cameras that can be configured to aim at an IP  and poke it whenever they scan some QR code? Thanks

Comment: @kohhworlwide, I really have no idea.  Be prepared to do some engineering.

Comment: You could always switch to something more active. Like pinging ultrasonic transmitters on the machines and strategically placed receivers around the building connected to a central controller to calculate the position based on trilateration.

Answer (score 0):

I've used RFID sensors and tags in a product. The RF tags we used are for short-range stuff but the UHF tags are used for detecting objects from further away. So this is detecting containers on lorries from 15 m away, the same sort of thing you're looking at.

The UHF readers are off-the-shelf and readily available. I don't know if you could mount the equipment above or to the side of the vehicle detection zone - you obviously want to be close enough to not falsely detect the vehicle behind. But you are getting a code from each tag so you can tell vehicles apart.

I don't know enough about your application but obviously the RFID route needs the compliance of the vehicle i.e. they have to agree to carry it and they might lose it. The metal-detecting route doesn't have that disadvantage. I'm sure you've already weighed these factors up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The detection would need to be nearly 3M from the vehicle. Detections could be happening from 3 different spots at the same time, so working with RFID do you think that the system can be made so that information isn't lost along the way?

What time of readers/tags would you recommend? Since this information would have to be processed ( 3 readers at 3 different lanes ) would you use a webserver or such to link the information?

Comment: @kohhworlwide, no need to thank me, you can use the upvote if it helped you :-)

Comment: I didn't finish the answer but wrongly sent it. haha

Comment: @kohhworlwide, this is an industry in itself so it's a product are for you to investigate, same as if I'd advocated a VGA monitor. Search the Interweb for 'UHF RFID', I've check that you'll find mountains there. Good luck.